# xrvt/xterm flickers in Ubuntu when using screen

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, console

I have xrvt running with the screen command, but it flickers every time I press, say the right arrow key. (It flickers white). Any ideas as to why?

Ps. Gnome terminal is hard to set up with 6x13 condensed bitmap fonts...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a default screen behaviour (it flashes instead of beeping your pc-speaker).

Try this while running screen:
setenv vbell off

Does the problem go away?

Comment: C-a C-g at least works. Where do I make it permanent? Thanks!

Comment: Screen's default is "visual bell", not "audible bell". That might help with any searching.

Comment: You can enter settings into ~/.screenrc, check the screen manpage for more info (man screen)

Answer (score 1):

Edit /etc/screenrc (and also inputrc if you wish) and turn bell and vbell to be off. This works for me.